# CSS Submenu Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, submenu

Hey guys my current menu is like this:

[image]

I need to make it so that the submenu does not make its parent width stretch (for both ul ul and ul ul ul) like this:

[image]

Here is a JS Fiddle I created to help:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NC8A/

Your Help is greatly apprecitated!

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but some how looks like your second image. Note that there are some fixed width values, and that may give you troubles, I'm sorry if it does not solve your problem.

```
#access ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: -70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#access ul ul li {
    float: left;
}
#access li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I would have to implement it without a fixed width. However I have now solved the problem by integrating another wordpress menu in the page and only displaying the submenu items.